# Node.js & MongoDB not reading variable correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Recently, I changed key of object in MongoDB.

```
{
 links: {
  changed: 'value',
  notchanged: 'value'
 }
}
```

This is what I get from my MongoDB collection. Data which key is not changed is still readable by `links.notchanged` but data which key is changed like `links.changed` is not readable and only outputs undefined. Node.js gets and reads the whole `links` data correctly but when it comes to `links.changed` it doesn't. How do I solve this problem? Code below:

```
scheme.findOne({}, (err, data) => {
  if (err) res.send('ERR')
  else {
    console.log(data) // prints full data, same as JSON above
    console.log(data.links.changed) // undefined
  }
}
```

Comment: if you can send the code, you are using, at least the part that seems to not work.

Comment: I updated it. It's simple code though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching `{class:'210'}`.. Is it available in document. Probably Your query returns empty object in data . Confirm the match query... Otherwise your code seems ok.

```
await db1.findOne({class: "210"}, (err, data) => {
        console.log(data.links.changed) // returns value
    })
```

Or Try the code like this

```
await db1.find({ class: "210" }).toArray()
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data[0].links.changed) //"value"
        });
```

Comment: I've modified my question. Can you check it? The problem is not that I can't get data from mongodb but nodejs prints `undefined` when printing values individually from JSON. class value has no problem as it has class value in full data. I've only uploaded data which is problem.

Comment: db1.findOne({})
        .then(data => {console.log(data.links.changed)})
        .catch(err => console.log(err));     (Try this code)

Answer (score 0):

You should make a variable instead of an object for this. For example: Use changed and assign it value as true or false